# Activity Label Text Alignment

Tags: android, android-activity, label

I want to know whether there is a way to change the ***alignment*** of activiy label, like other views can be aligned by *android:gravity attribute*..

**NOTE**: Except  *android:label="  Header "*

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  have to customize Title Bar for that.

See the Examples Here :

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/06/16/custom-title-bar-in-android/

You can customize according to your need.